# How do I make sure alla data is restored using SMO?

Tags: sql-server, restore, smo

A restore performed with C# code using SMO objects restores fine when original database is in SIMPLE recovery mode. We got problems with one database where the restore missed all content from a certain table, where all data was inserted late in process. The database showed to be in BULK LOGGED recovery mode. After changing to SIMPLE and doing a new backup, it restored fine, using our code.

We have tried different settings on the restore object, but found none that fixes the problem. We are under the impression that the restoring ignores data in the log.

The basic restore looks like this:

```
sqlServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(instanceName));
restore = GetRestore();
restore.PercentComplete += PercentCompleteAction;
restore.Complete += CompleteAction;
restore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
```

the GetRestore function is basically implemented like this:

```
restore = new Restore();
var deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(backupFileName, DeviceType.File);
restore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
restore.Database = newDatabaseName;
restore.NoRecovery = false;
restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
restore.ReplaceDatabase = false;
return restore;
```

There are no error messages - just missing content in one table.

Added try:
I took a guess at the solution below, but it didn't help:

```
restore.ReplaceDatabase = false;
restore.NoRecovery = true;
restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
restore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
restore.NoRecovery = true;
restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Log;
restore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
restore.NoRecovery = false;
restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Files;
restore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with any `BULK LOGGED` problems and switching to SIMPLE reduces availability, it doesn't fix problems. `BULK LOGGED` is the same as Fully logged except for specific bulk operations. Changes since the last backup are kept in the transaction log until it gets backed up itself. This makes recover *easier*. It also means you can take small transaction log backups in addition to a full backup, eg every 1 hour or 15 minutes and be able to restore everything up to the last hour's data, instead of the last day's or week's.

Comment: `SIMPLE` on the other hand deletes transaction log entries once a transaction completes. This means you can't take any log backups, and can only restore to the last data backup.

Comment: Most likely the last data backup was taken when that table was empty and there were no transaction log backups. Moving to simple won't fix that. It doesn't even affect how backup and restore behaves, only how the transaction log is used

Comment: `the restore missed all content from a certain table, where all data was inserted late in process.` This probably means the data changes *weren't* committed when the data backup was taken. They'd still appear in the transaction log. Restoring the transaction log would bring them back. With SIMPLE there won't be any transaction log entries left, so there won't be any chance of recovering them

Comment: I think you are right in your last comment, and the problem then becomes: How do I make sure a transaction log will be restored into target data? I added a try in my question, but to no help.

Comment: You haven't posted *how* you took those backups. Use the correct command, `BACKUP LOG`. Check [Back Up a Transaction Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-a-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). Even when you use the SMO API you end up executing the same SQL commands. It's actually a lot more common to execute the BACKUP commands than using SMO. You should understand what you need to backup and how often, based on your recovery requirements - how much data are you willing to lose, and how fast do you want to recover?

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-sql-server-databases?view=sql-server-2017) explain the various backup strategies and the implications. A lot of people are using [Ola Hallengren's backup scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) to make backups easier, especially when multiple databases are involved.

Comment: You could [automate maintenance](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/automate-and-improve-your-database-maintenance-using-ola-hallengrens-free-script/) by running eg. a full backup once a week, a differential backup once a day and transaction log backups every hour or 15 minutes, depending on how much you're willing to lose in case of failure. Recovery time is a concern too - you'll have to restore multiple transaction logs after a failure which obviously takes more than a full or full+diff restore

Comment: Actually this has not much to do with backup strategy. Our little program is there to assist when copying databases between servers. I could rephrase my question: How do I make sure alla data is restored using SMO?

Comment: You can't restore what isn't backed up. Uncommitted changes won't be restored, no matter what. They don't exist yet - that's what uncommitted means. If the server restarted unexpectedly those changes would be rolled back, no matter what recovery model is used.

Comment: As for how to copy a database, that's already available in SSMS through the [Copy Database wizard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-2017). The `Detach` method is the fastest and safest, but requires taking the database offline. You detach the database, copy its data and log files to the new server and attach them again. You can perform the same steps through [T-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-a-database-using-detach-and-attach-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: The "SMO method" essentially scripts the source database, recreates it in the new server and copies the data over. The wizard itself creates an SSIS package with Detach, File Copy, Attach or Copy Object steps. You can save that package and schedule it for execution.

Comment: I suspect the problem with your current technique is that you're trying to take a backup *after* some job starts an ETL job that clears a target table inside a transaction. Take the backup *before* that transaction starts instead, or wait for it to commit first

Answer (score 0):

You need select a correct FileNumber in your Log file, see this method can solve your problem:

```
public static void restaurarBackup(string pathFileBak)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.getCon());
        Server smoServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

        string localFilePath = pathFileBak;
        string db_name = "ETrade";
        string defaultFolderEtrade = @"C:\ETrade\";
        Restore rs = new Restore();
        rs.NoRecovery = false;
        rs.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        BackupDeviceItem bdi = default(BackupDeviceItem);
        bdi = new BackupDeviceItem(localFilePath, DeviceType.File);
        rs.Devices.Add(bdi);
        DataTable dt = rs.ReadFileList(smoServer);
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            string logicalFilename = r.ItemArray[dt.Columns["LogicalName"].Ordinal].ToString();
            string physicalFilename = defaultFolderEtrade + Path.GetFileName(r.ItemArray[dt.Columns["PhysicalName"].Ordinal].ToString());
            rs.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalFilename, physicalFilename));
        }
        DataTable backupHeaders = rs.ReadBackupHeader(smoServer);
        rs.FileNumber = Convert.ToInt32(backupHeaders.AsEnumerable().Max(backupInfo => backupInfo["Position"]));
        rs.Database = db_name;
        smoServer.KillAllProcesses(rs.Database);
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database db = smoServer.Databases[rs.Database];
        db.DatabaseOptions.UserAccess = DatabaseUserAccess.Single;
        rs.SqlRestore(smoServer);

        db = smoServer.Databases[rs.Database];
        db.SetOnline();
        smoServer.Refresh();
        db.Refresh();
    }
```

If you want look backups in your Log file, [see this query](https://luizlima.net/casos-do-dia-a-dia-erro-restore-log-the-log-in-this-backup-set-begins-at-lsn-xxx-which-is-too-recent-to-apply-to-the-database/):

```
SELECT database_name, name, backup_start_date, 
backup_finish_date, datediff(mi, backup_start_date, backup_finish_date) [tempo (min)],
 position, first_lsn, last_lsn, server_name, recovery_model, 
 type, cast(backup_size/1024/1024 as numeric(15,2)) [Tamanho (MB)], B.is_copy_only
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset B
```